# Force optional parameters to be required for some setting

Tags: python, python-2.7, parameters, parameter-passing, optional-parameters

I have created some class,

```
class c:
    def __init__(self, mode=False):
        if mode:
            force foo to require optional_parameter

    def foo(self, optional_parameter=""):
        print("something %s" % optional_parameter)
```

Is there a way that if the class is instantiated with `mode=True` that all `optional_parameter` values are required when calling the method, effectively no longer optional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remember `mode` in an attribute, and check if `optional_parameter` has been passed:

```
class c:
    def __init__(self, mode=False):
        self.mode = mode

def foo(self, optional_parameter=""):
    if self.mode and optional_parameter == "":
        raise RuntimeError("optional_parameter must be passed")
    print("something %s" % optional_parameter)
```

You could generalize this with a dictionary unpacking:

```
def foo(self, **kwargs):
    if self.mode and 'optional_parameter' not in kwargs:
        raise RuntimeError("optional_parameter must be passed")
    print("something %s" % kwargs['optional_parameter'])
```

I cannot find the best exception for this situation, you might want to create your own. I would be ok with using [`RuntimeError`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.RuntimeError) though.

Comment: Great answer. If you also want to allow the caller to use the default value, you can create a sentinel object `c_opt_default = object()`, set it as the default  and check `if self.mode and optional_parameter is c_opt_default:`

Comment: I'd vote `TypeError` which is the same as missing required positional arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You could also define the `foo` method in the constructor:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, mode=False):
        self.mode = mode
        self.foo = (self._foo_mandatory if mode else
                    lambda optional_parameter="": self._foo_mandatory(optional_parameter))

    def _foo_mandatory(self, optional_parameter):
        print("something {0}".format(optional_parameter))

>>> c1 = C(False)
>>> c1.foo("Good")
something Good
>>> c1.foo()
something 

>>> c2 = C(True)
>>> c2.foo("Bad")
something Bad
>>> c2.foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
TypeError: _foo_mandatory() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```